# IE aborting http post requests with error 0x2ee2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I am using angularjs to upload files to my API. On my page, I have a muti-file select, and once the user selects 1 or more files, the page calls my api and uploads them one request per file, something like (not my exact code):

```
var promises = [];
angular.forEach(files, function(value) {
  promises.push(this.$http.post(this.baseApiUrl + '/files', fd)
            .then((response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): any => {
                return response.data;
            })
```

}

This works fine in all browsers except IE (of course). In IE, if there are more than about 20 files, most of them will work fine, but a couple of the requests will get aborted. There doesn't seem to be any pattern, they will just randomly get aborted. The request actually makes it to the API, but the browser gives up on the request and acts like it failed (its not a timeout). The error IE gives me is:
XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2.

Of course, I cannot find a list of XMLHttpRequest error codes, so i have no idea what 00002ee2 means. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to mainly be an issue with IE 11, cant seem to reproduce in IE 10.

Comment: So the hex code returned is 12002 in decimal, which according to this page:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/193625, means a timeout assuming IE uses WinINet which I think it does. Still doesnt explain why this is happening though. It seems to timeout after just a second or two and it seems completely random.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, It happens in IE 11 when the POST request takes time to reply back. Did you happen to get a workaround or soemthing?

Answer (score 0):

2ee2 hex to decimal = 12002

[IE aborting http post requests with error 0x2ee2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631874/ie-aborting-http-post-requests-with-error-0x2ee2)

Code        Error Message and Description
12002       ERROR_INTERNET_TIMEOUT
            The request has timed out.

FIX: Something stops server from answering. In my case the server was waiting on a break point in debug mode :)